# Winforms data binding and INotifyPropertyChanged on mono

Tags: c#, winforms, mono, monodevelop, inotifypropertychanged

I've made my first mono application running on a raspberry pi. The problem is that the data binding did not update the UI. To be more specific the PropertyChanged event inside my controller/model is null. That means there is no subscriber.

When I run the application on windows inside the visual studio debugger, the ui gets properly updated.

Mono version: 4.6.2
OS: Raspbian Wheezy
.NET: 4.5

I've found not much information on that scenario. As it works on windows and mono supports the INotifyPropertyChanged interface, I assumed that it will also run in mono on linux.

`// creating the binding in code
            dhtControl.labelName.DataBindings.Add("Text", dht, "Name");`

I think there is no other code needed, as it is the default INotifyPropertyChanged implementation. The only difference is that I pass an Action (control.Invoke) to the model to Invoke the update on the main thread.

Regards

Comment: Did you end up figuring this out? I'm running into the same issue.

Comment: I've figured that when adding data bindings, they do not register to the PropertyChangedEvent with Mono, but they do with .Net. Still no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, solved adding an action event fired by the ViewModel, where update all the controls:

```
internal void InvokeUIControl(Action action)
    {
        // Call the provided action on the UI Thread using Control.Invoke() does not work in MONO
        //this.Invoke(action);

        // do it manually
        this.lblTemp.Invoke(new Action(() => this.lblTemp.Text = ((MainViewModel)(((Delegate)(action)).Target)).Temperature));
        this.lblTime.Invoke(new Action(() => this.lblTime.Text = ((MainViewModel)(((Delegate)(action)).Target)).Clock));           
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had noticed a difference between .NET and Mono and I got the same problem. After comparing .NET and Mono source code it appears first that if you want received an propertyName notification in ViewForm any Control.TextChanged you first have to in your Model :

```
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public event EventHandler TextChanged;

    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            if (propertyName == "Text")
            {
                TextChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }
    }
```

It's important that the event handler is named "TextChanged" in order to notify a TextChanged.
Then still in your model, you can set :

```
    private string _Text = "";
    public string Text {
        get {
            return _Text;
        }
        set {
            if (_Text != value) {
                NotifyPropertyChanged ("Text");
            }
        }
    }
```

And now, in your view you can do something like this.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace EventStringTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Model md = Model.Instance;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", md, "Text", false
                , DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
            this.OnBindingContextChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
            textBox1.TextChanged += (object sender, System.EventArgs e) => { };
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs evt)
        {
            md.PropertyChanged += (object s, PropertyChangedEventArgs e) => { };

            // This is just to start make Text Changed in Model.
            md.TimerGO ();
        }
    }
}
```

This seems a lot of code, but I'm still searching a elegant even better solution.

Answer (score 0):

are they any new experiences in this case?
I started a new project to develop a remote app for Raspberry (RS232,GUI and http act/response) and won´t change my programming language - C#.
I got a lot of quick goals on points I wouldn´t expected - serial and GPIO works fine with code written in VS2022 - but I don´t expected a stop sign at this point.
A simple text onto a button wont update after a the INotifyPropertyChanged event is fired. Exact as it described here. What I figured out is, that the Event is recognized in the maincode. I subscribe a delegate to the ViewModel Event and the delegate was called.

```
viewModel.PropertyChanged += UpdateLabel;
```

[A solved initial problem (beginners failure) with the complete small code is here](https://mycsharp.de/forum/threads/125080/keine-aenderung-button-text-bei-viewmodel-inotifypropertychanged-binding)

Answer (score 0):

An work around is define separate *PropertyName*Changed event for each property of your control.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).